# How to fix this "state/country" dropdown issue in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, drop-downs

I have a problem with the **state / country** dropdown in

> "Customer Information > Addresses > Edit Customer's Address".

***1/ When USA is selected by default there was a state dropdown :***

[image]

***2/ Next I select UK : the dropdown disappears***

[image]

***3/ I re-select USA but the state dropdown is still hidden :***

[image]

Do you know how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **Configuration > General > States Options** and set **Display not required State** to **Yes**

Comment: Thanks it works !